# CORS not working using CORS Filter where client and server is in same url

Tags: java, cors

I am trying to implement CORS where the client and server are in the same URL using CORS Filter.
Below is the code I have implemented

**CORS Filter**

```
package com.core.web.spring.cors;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class CORSFilter implements Filter{

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        ((HttpServletResponse) res).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://192.168.0.103:1111");
        ((HttpServletResponse) res).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "GET, POST");
        ((HttpServletResponse) res).addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
        
    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.core.web.spring.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
  
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I have set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin as http://192.168.0.103:1111. I am changing the origin to http://192.168.0.108:1111 from the postman tool. But instead of blocking the request, it is executing it. I am getting a successful response.

Below is the request header and response header

**Request Header**

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1296
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`enter code here`
Host: 192.168.0.103:1111
Origin: http://192.168.0.108:1111
Referer: http://192.168.0.103:1111/SampleTest/index.html
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

**Response Header**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://192.168.0.103:1111
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1210
Date: Sat, 03 Jul 2021 06:11:55 GMT
Server: WildFly/11
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=7776000; includeSubdomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Postman doesn't care about SOP (Same-Origin Policy), it's a dev tool, not a browser.

CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) and SOP (Same-Origin Policy) are server-side configurations that clients decide to enforce or not.

Related to clients

Most Browsers do enforce it to prevent issues related to CSRF attacks.
Most Development tools don't care about it. Postman being dev tool will not give much importance to CORS header, you will need something else to test.

There are chrome extensions that can help you test CORS on your browser.